# Mutating numbers in timeout with onPush detection strategy

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, immutability

I want to set a default value of a parameter and mutate it after 2 seconds, that's what I have:

```
@Input() num: number;

ngOnInit() {
  this.num = 1;
  setTimeout(() => ++this.num, 2000);
}
```

And in the view:

```
{{ num }}
```

It works perfectly with a default detection strategy, but stops working when I add `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to the component decorator (the value is always `1` and never changes).

Why is that so? I thought `onPush` strategy compares only references, and assigning a new integer always changes a reference?

Answer (score 1):

`OnPush` strategy detects change when the `@Input` property changed from parent component. You can inject `ChangeDetectorRef` to your component. You may find [this article](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4) helpful.

```
@Input() num: number;

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.num = 1;
  setTimeout(() => {
    ++this.num, 2000;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  });
}
```